# Installing official Google Marketplace on a chinese Asus Eee Pad Transformer 101

Tags: google-play-store, accounts, google-account, asus-eee-pad-transformer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, …) on my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device)

I'm currently living in China,
so I bought my Asus Eee Pad Transformer 101 here.

For some reason it does not come with the official Google Marketplace application
but with some other application that only supports chinese as a UI language and uses some
other "less official" market place.

I did find the Market App from google and installed it.

However when I start it it tells me

> You must add an account to the device to continue. Do you want to add
>   one now?

If I click Yes, I'm simply redirected to the home screen (the app remains open in the background)

Does anybody know of a way to set this up? Because the only thing  was able to 
add to the device was my gmail account for e-mail.

Thnx.

Comment: I think you'll probably need to root and install another ROM with proper Google Account support, but I'm not familiar with this.

Comment: But these roms cannot be legally downloaded right?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASUS's terms but I would assume they would not disallow you from downloading their official ROM from another region to your device.  That said, obtaining the Market separately may have been questionably legal :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to do it.

There are some alternative market places that can be used, but they don't solve the fact that tablets with the chinese firmware are rendered useless because there's no Google account support.

So the only thing you can do really is install this:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1245892

Works like a charm :)

Oh and for the Prime, Asus officially supports it.