# Google Play Store on a Samsung Galaxy Ace missing

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-ace

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace with Android 2.3.4. The phone came with Samsung App Store not the Google market. I would like to install the Google market or Google Play as there is a better selection of apps. However the play.google.com website has no link to download the store. What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not included? It should be! Do you have Gmail?

Comment: Maybe its under old name "Market".

Comment: Not under a different name. There are two app stores on the phone, Samsung App Store and Wo Store (Wo is the China Unicom 3G network).

Comment: Are you missing other Google framework Apps? Maybe your device has for some reason no Google license and therefore comes without the Google framework (Market, Maps, Talk, etc.).

Comment: It has no google apps at all. No maps, gmail, talk or other. There are the networks own branded alternatives.

Comment: Ouch... The only alternative I can think of is flashing a custom rom with the GAPPS on top of that http://goo.im/gapps/

Comment: That's a problem with *Chinese Editions*. Please check the following Q&As: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24768/does-china-mobile-galaxy-s3-model-gt-i-9308-have-google-play-store / http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13081/installing-official-google-marketplace-on-a-chinese-asus-eee-pad-transformer-101

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I install the Google Apps Package (Play Store, ...) on my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27808/how-can-i-install-the-google-apps-package-play-store-on-my-android-device)

Answer (score -1):

The update is OTA - so if you are scheduled to receive it for your device (which I believe you should have) - you should go to Settings >> About >> System Updates - and check for an update.

You may need to update your device to 2.3.5 to receive the update.